# Can not return to my house after falling in lava

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My house is next to a village from the Steve seed number. While I was digging in the well for diamonds I fell in lava and it took me in the middle of nowhere, now I can't get back to my house

When it's supposed to spawn me back to my house?

Comment: when you first entered the world did you start near this village/where your house is, if not have you used a bed in your house?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: Please help I worked so long and hard subs now it's all just gone

Comment: your not playing the hardcore difficulty where when you die your world is gone (never played it myself so not sure if the world just resets of if your thrown back to the title).

Comment: @Memor-X hardcore would have deleted everything and taken him back to the menu- that's not it.

Comment: Press F3. What coordinates are you at now?

Answer (score 2):

The game is not supposed to automatically spawn you at your house, you need to have a bed in your house and to have slept at least once in it for the game to change your respawn coordinates.

Even when you have a bed if it is obstructed you can't respawn there, but the game is showing an error message for this.

So you certainly respawned at the original spawn point of your world, to find your house you need to remember the path you took the first time to build your house, or you can give yourself the permission to fly (creative or any other way) to look around and find your house.

Comment: the OP has stated in the comments that he has used a bed in his house

Comment: Maybe he didn't sleep in it, maybe it was obstructed.
And if he really did sleep in it, it still didn't make him respawn there, so its the third paragraph of my answer.

Comment: He said he used it, please read the comment, and as you stated there would have been an error message if it was obstructed, so he would know that was the cause.

Comment: "if not have you used a bed in your house?" to what he answered "Yes", this is not explicit enough for me, a lot of people would say that if they just placed it, but not actually slept in it, and talking about experience, I often had to help friends on minecraft who were just not reading error messages or just didn't even see them because they clicked too fast.

But anyways, whatever the cause is, what happened is that he didn't respawn at his bed location, and the first thing to do is to find the house again.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in understanding that your house was near where you first spawned in the world, as you seem to have said in the comments to your post, then you should be able to find it with a little searching. Go to 0,0 and look all around within a few hundred blocks, and you should find your house.

If you haven't used coordinates before, what you do is tap F3, and find the numbers that are labeled X, Y, and Z. X and Z are your lateral coordinates, and Y is your height (0-255). Walk in such a way as to make X and Z both go to zero.

Once you are there, you should find your house within a few hundred blocks of 0,0. If you're trying to do this without any cheats, you can make a [map](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map) centered on 0,0 and zoom it out once (see linked article), that way you can see where you've already searched.